# Why gas gets soluble in water?

Tags: energy, atomic-physics, gas

What is the reason behind solubility of gas in water(closed vessel)? Actually gas tends to move freely, then why it restricts its motion by its own by getting dissolved?

Also, why whole gas doesn't get dissolved in water in a closed vessel of gas and water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what do you mean by solubility?

At Layman level, The molecule of the solute get stuck in the inter-molecular space of solvent (here water).

> What is the reason behind solubility of gas in water(closed vessel)?

When you pass a gas through a liquid, it might be possible that some lower energetic gas particle get reside in the inter-molecular space of liquid.(say water)

> Actually gas tends to move freely, then why it restricts its motion by
> its own by getting dissolved?

Not all of the gas molecule get dissolve. Only some fraction get dissolved. The solubility of a gas mainly depends upon temperature and pressure.

you Increase the pressure, in a confined volume, that means you are restricting the molecule, you will find that the solubility will increase. Like in soda Can, until you open the bottle, carbon dioxide is dissolved. when you open the cap, decreasing the pressure, the gas escapes. thus solubility is decreased.

Now, Say Increase the temperature , means increase the kinetic energy, the solubility will decrease and Vice versa.

> why whole gas doesn't get dissolved in water in a closed vessel of gas
> and water?

They will dissolve according to the temperature and pressure applied.
Under Normal circumstances, in a closed vessel they will not dissolve. Its not that the ocean dissolve all the atmosphere on earth.(If you Take earth as a closed System)